# BASH Script to autologin into browser

Tags: chromium

I am having some issues with my script. I'm trying to load NagiOS dashboard on the TV using RaspberryPI. This is my current script which opens the browser and directs the user to the page in kiosk mode. I need to be able to feed the login details so this is all done automatically when TV is turned on.

```
#!/bin/sh
DISPLAY=:0.0 ; export DISPLAY
unclutter &
sleep 30
chromium-browser \
--kiosk \
--ignore-certificate-errors \
--disable-restore-session-state \
http://domain.com &
x11vnc -forever
```

Comment: First, sh is not bash. Next, whether this is possible depend on the options of chromium, and has nothing to do with your shell interpreter.

Comment: Apologies if I got the bash and .sh wrong, any solution?

Comment: I'm a pretty good dabbler at bash but not at all when it comes to Chromium. So I retagged the question and handed it over to the right guys who might point you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway, the Chromium browser has certain switches and none are helpful for the autologin, there must be a script that can be written that would auto logs you into the website http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: "there must be a script that can be written that would auto logs you into the website" I doubt that. Typically it's hard to interact with GUI programs, unless they expose the features you want. (Even with CLI programs, you can't do anything when they don't expose the necessary API.)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll call this one a no solution and move on i guess.